# Howto get currentTime inside timeupdate event (apply & bind)

Tags: javascript, html5-video, html5-audio, typescript2.0

How to get curentTime from Html5 Audio.I did not place audio html tag . I just want to do it in typescript.i get TypeError: Cannot read property 'currentTime' of undefined. I think there is something wrong with current context ? how can i fix it with apply & bind or any other technique ?

```
//player.ts

 audio = new Audio(); 
btnPlay(){ 
    this.audio.src = "media/Audio_1.mp3";     
    this.audio.load();
    this.audio.play();
    this.audio.addEventListener('timeupdate',this.timeupdate)
 }
timeupdate(e){  
  console.log(this.audio.currentTime); 
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make `timeupdate` an arrow function:

```
timeupdate = (e) => {  
  console.log(this.audio.currentTime); 
}
```

See https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#this-and-arrow-functions for more information.